# Android: start service with parameter

Tags: android, parameters, service, android-activity

To start my service from an Activiy I use `startService(MyService.class)`. This works great, but in a special case the service should be started differently. I want to pass some parameters to the service start.

I tried the following in my Activity:

```
Intent startMyService= new Intent();
startMyService.setClass(this,LocalService.class);
startMyService.setAction("controller");
startMyService.putExtra(Constants.START_SERVICE_CASE2, true);

startService(startMyService);
```

In my Service I use:

```
public class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("controller")) 
        {
                // Intent was received                               
        }

    }
}
```

The IntentReceiver is registered in onCreate() like this:

```
IntentFilter mControllerIntent = new IntentFilter("controller");
MyIntentReceiver mIntentReceiver= new MyIntentReceiver();
registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, mControllerIntent);
```

With this solution the service starts but the intent is not received. **How can I start a Service and pass my parameters?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is MyIntentReceiver for? Do you want to listen to some specific broadcast and alter your service behavior?

Comment: @Audrius: Yes, you're right. The MyIntentReceiver is used to change the behaviour of my service. There are 2 states in my service: One when starting the service, another when the service is running.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step #1: Delete your `BroadcastReceiver` implementation.

Step #2: Examine the `Intent` your service gets in `onStartCommand()` and look at the action via `getAction()`.

Comment: But this will allow to change service only after onCreate. I i want to pass variable in the oncreate, then how to do it

Answer (score 33):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,ListenLocationService.class); 
serviceIntent.putExtra("From", "Main");
startService(serviceIntent);
//and get the parameter in onStart method of your service class

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(extras == null) {
        Log.d("Service","null");
    } else {
        Log.d("Service","not null");
        String from = (String) extras.get("From");
        if(from.equalsIgnoreCase("Main"))
            StartListenLocation();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get the intent object in onStartCommand method of service class

Comment: As well as in the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`