# how to call stopService from another Activity?

Tags: android

New to android programming. 
Could you please let me know how to pass the view as parameter?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  ...
  public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
  }
}

public class MySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  ...
  MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
  obj.stopService();
}
```

I have coded MyService.java correctly.

Thank you

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301891/android-start-service-with-parameter

Comment: I am slowing understanding this. right now, this seems to work ... 
`context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));`
Thanks for all the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to unbind the service from the previous activity in onStop(). Otherwise you may met a window leaked exception.

Place the code to stop the service in the **Application class**.

```
public class AppController extends Application {
  private static AppController mInstance;

  public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
  }
  .........

  public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
  }
}
```

Then you can get the Application object from any class and you will be able to stop the service from any activity, but before that you have to unbind the service from the other activity in `onStop()`.

To stop the service from anywhere, call:

```
AppController.getInstance().stopService();
```

Comment: hi User,
Can you please explain this in detail. Or please provide an example?

I have onStartCommand() and onDestroy in MyService.java.

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Comment: if your service is binded service, then you have to call unboundService()  from the same context.check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614335/android-how-to-safely-unbind-a-service

Comment: Worked for me... Thank you, you saved me from a big headache :)